# How to make page not publishable?

Tags: 2011, cme

We are routinely rolling out new features which require us to publish all the pages, but we have some pages which are in the review stage and we don't want to publish those pages.

Manually maintaining the list of these pages is difficult. Is there a way to make a page not publishable? If that is possible, we will just mark it un-publishable until it is ready, then we change it back to be publishable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For sake of completeness you could also use a custom resolver. This might look at some page level metadata to verify whether the page is publishable or not. If not publishable, remove it from the resolved set.

I still would recommend the workflow approach, as that's the solution that matches your requirement the most.

Comment: I like to keep this at the page level, instead of doing it via "disable publishing" template. I believe both are good solutions, I prefer this one. It is easier to understand conceptually.   Thanks again, as always.

Comment: The custom resolver has a nice side benefit of giving authors a chance to see pages they're queuing up when publishing items they use or vice versa--knowing a publish won't queue unwanted pages. One tip for the metadata: I'd recommend a text set to a Category (even with a single keyword) over a "Boolean" field approach. It'll give you flexibility for changes which you might use for workflow later.

Answer (score 10):

Have you looked at the workflow functionality of SDL Tridion?  I think you can easily solve this using workflow, the concept is that you have an approval status on your publication targets, if your content isn't approved to the correct status, it wont publish to a specific target.

It's also possible to modify structure groups to make them 'Unpublishable' - that might also be a solution for you.

Comment: Yes, workflow is the proper solution for the long term. I am looking for some shortcut :-)

Comment: hi charles, i think @mihai has a good solution then

Comment: As a shortcut and to prepare for workflow, you could publish using bundles without workflow. Rather than at a page level, authors would publish sets of approved pages. Automation would then be on the content manager side (perhaps Event System to avoid adding non-approved pages).

Answer (score 5):

I have another thought that you can handle this through a Simple Component Template called **"Disable Publishing"**.

### Steps to Create a "Disable Publishing" template:

1. Get the user specific message from the Generic component
2. Throw an exception with the "User Specific Message"
3. Message should ideally tell that "why publishing is disabled"

### Where to use:

You can add this Component Presentation on any page and while CP is rendering it will throw an exception and page will get failed with the proper message.

Comment: That's one way to go. If you choose this, you might want to alternatively use some metadata at page level.

Comment: The side effect here would be that when you publish a structure group or a component it will fail the entire publish transaction, so nothing will get published

Comment: @MihaiCădariu: Yes, there is a side effect but user should give an update to content author, not to publish SG for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Well, if page is published as result of a "where used" resolving (eg. Publishing a component like when using Experience Manager) then the side effect shows again.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two Tridion features to achieve this:

Firstly, you create a structure group for the pages that you don't want to be publishable. Structure groups *do* have a Publishable flag, so you can make the structure group unpublishable.

Then all you need to do is cut and paste the pages into the non-publishable structure group. If you need to maintain structure, you can still use the same technique; just make a hierarchy of unpublishable structure groups that matches your real hierarchy.

When the pages are fully reviewed, just cut and paste them back.